# Add Ghost blog to existing Google App Engine Flask App

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, ghost-blog

I'm trying to add a Ghost blog to an existing Flask app hosted on Google App Engine. I want the blog to show up on a subdirectory (e.g. www.example.com/blog). I'm open to hosting the blog wherever, but would prefer to use ghost.org's hosting. Is this possible? I was thinking there should be a way to do it in the app.yaml file, but can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Are you willing to use the paid Ghost(Pro)?  They will host it for you, and you just provide the user a portal to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to pay for it, but I want it to be on my existing domain, is this possible thru CNAMES or some other way?

Comment: Yes.  Contact them.

Answer (score 0):

Ghost(Pro) supports subdomain installs for all plans, and subdirectory installs for the top two plans (team, business). If you contact support they'll send you the info on how to set it up using either an nginx or apache proxy.

Self-hosting on a subdirectory is also relatively straight forward, especially if you use Ghost-CLI & the recommended stack. Ghost-CLI asks what URL you want to use, and then does all of the necessary configuration (Ghost config, nginx, ssl, systemd, etc) for you.

I don't know anything about Google App Engine to recommend how it could be done there, but as you've said you're open to hosting anywhere DigitalOcean have a 1 click installer, and any standard VPS that uses ubuntu will support using Ghost-CLI e.g. Linode.